# A cloud storage package that supports a .gitignore style file

Tags: cloud-storage

I need a cloud (not self hosted unless its very simple to setup) storage product that supports a .gitignore style file. Eg I have

c:\sync\folder1.syncignore

c:\sync is the root folder, everything inside of folder1 that matches the .syncignore format is ignored without warning.

The requirement for without warning is important. So far I have not found a single cloud hosted product that will do this.

OneDrive allows blanket blocking file extensions however you this shows hundreds of warnings if you have these files in your onedrive.

Dropbox, google drive, sync, OneDrive, all do not seem to support anything like this.

Requirements are it has a windows client (like onedrive, dropbox etc). History and does not lock files. LAN transfer to other known clients would be amazing.

Can someone list a product which supports a .syncignore file or describe a method to achieve this. Self hosted is an option if it is simple to set up. We have access to azure blob storage.

Comment: Interested to hear if you found a nice option. For me one additional requirement is a (decent) Linux client.

Comment: I did not find one

Answer (score 2):

Nextcloud now supports such behavior, though some have described the feature as buggy.

See the [issue in the tracker](https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/pull/1374).

Nextcloud is self hosted, but I believe that most would characterize setup as simple.

Answer (score 0):

By searching for the term "syncignore" on the web I found two ooptions (and [this superuser question asking something similar](https://superuser.com/q/1566846/141595):

- [Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/) seems to support an [IgnoreList file](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205458165-Ignoring-files-in-Sync-Ignore-List-), similar to a ".gitignore" file:

  > IgnoreList is a UTF-8 encoded text file that allows you to specify single files, paths or rules for ignoring during the synchronization job. Each line of the IgnoreList file represents a separate rule.

  However, Resilio Sync works between network connected devices, so you would still need your own "cloud" or network location where you can sync to.
- [Koofr](https://koofr.eu/) supports a [".syncignore" file](https://koofr.eu/blog/posts/advanced-ways-to-exclude-files-from-sync-part-2), similar to a ".gitignore" file:

  > To be able to use the advanced exclusion (or inclusion) rules, you'll need to create a .syncignore file in the root of the folder that is being synced ...
  > Inside the .syncignore file, write one exclusion/inclusion rule per line using the glob format.

Koofr seems to function as a meta-cloud-syncer, it can sync to different existing cloud storage providers (e.g. Google Drive, OneDrive, etc...).